# Window actions vs Server actions in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo-10

In the scaffolded module there are two alternatives of the actions defined: a **window action** and a **server action**.

But what is the difference of those actions conceptually and when to use which of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Window action*, we are register Tree,Form,Kanban,Calendar etc ids. Based on priority, it will open related view.

While *Server action* are useful for following different-different purpose with selected Base model.

- Send Email
- Execute Python Code
- Trigger a Workflow signal
- Run client action
- Create or Copy a new Record
- Write a Record
- Execute several actions

Comment: @Odera, Can you give me an example to create new record with server action? Earlier I wrote one with `code` field, but it is not beauty solution. If I know well, `use_create` field is a built tool for it.

Comment: @Döme, for example we want to add Sale Order history whenever new Sale order is created. For that we will create a *server action* with *Create or Copy a new Record* *model=sale.order* So It will execute logic which we have implement  in *server action*

Comment: @Odera, it is clear, but what is the relevant xml code? eg.: should that work? `<field name="use_create" model="model.model">new</field>`

Comment: @Döme, nope. Try with `<field name="kind">on_create</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order"/>` put *sale* module in your dependency.